# Different repository in DistributionManagement and Repositories

Tags: java, maven, nexus

In `<DistributionManagement> ... </DistributionManagement> 
and <Repositories> ... <Repositories>` sections, there can be a

```
<Repository> ... </Repository>
```

definition. What's the difference between the two  definition? This is one example:

```
<distributionManagement>

                <downloadUrl>https://github.com/marytts/marytts/releases</downloadUrl>
                <repository>
                        <id>bintray</id>
                        <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/marytts/marytts/marytts</url>
                </repository>
                <snapshotRepository>
                        <id>bintray</id>
                        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local</url>
                </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>
```

And

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>marytts-dependencies</id>
                <name>marytts-dependencies</name>
                <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <url>file://${project.local.repository.path}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>jcenter</name>
                <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Distribution Management**

> Distribution management acts precisely as it sounds: it manages the
>   distribution of the artifact and supporting files generated throughout
>   the build process. Starting with the last elements first:

**Repository**

> Where as the repositories element specifies in the POM the location
>   and manner in which Maven may download remote artifacts for use by the
>   current project, distributionManagement specifies where (and how) this
>   project will get to a remote repository when it is deployed. The
>   repository elements will be used for snapshot distribution if the
>   snapshotRepository is not defined.

**Deploy using the repository layout**

To deploy your file using the maven layout you should define the distribution management location  :

```
<project>
    ...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
              <id>myrepository</id>
              <url>file:D:/repository/</url>
        </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Then you just need to execute the following command to get you artifact copied in your file system location

Maven command to deploy a file in the local file system

```
mvn deploy
```

**Site Distribution**

> More than distribution to the repositories, distributionManagement is
>   responsible for defining how to deploy the project's site and
>   documentation.

In `pom.xml`, configure where to deploy your site within  `distributionManagement`  tag.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>mkyongserver</id>
      <url>dav:http://127.0.0.1/sites/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

**Relocation**

> Projects are not static; they are living things (or dying things, as
>   the case may be). A common thing that happens as projects grow, is
>   that they are forced to move to more suitable quarters. For example,
>   when your next wildly successful open source project moves under the
>   Apache umbrella, it would be good to give your users as heads-up that
>   the project is being renamed to org.apache:my-project:1.0. Besides
>   specifying the new address, it is also good form to provide a message
>   explaining why.

**Repositories**

> Repositories are collections of artifacts which adhere to the Maven
>   repository directory layout. In order to be a Maven repository
>   artifact, a POM file must live within the structure
>   $BASE_REPO/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom.
>   $BASE_REPO can be local (file structure) or remote (base URL); the
>   remaining layout will be the same. Repositories exist as a place to
>   collect and store artifacts. Whenever a project has a dependency upon
>   an artifact, Maven will first attempt to use a local copy of the
>   specified artifact. If that artifact does not exist in the local
>   repository, it will then attempt to download from a remote repository.
>   The repository elements within a POM specify those alternate
>   repositories to search.
>
> The repository is one of the most powerful features of the Maven
>   community. The default central Maven repository lives on
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. Another source for artifacts not
>   yet in iBiblio is the Codehaus snapshots repo.

Be remember you can add only one `<repository>` and one `<snapshotRepository>` child inside `<distributionManagement>`

How to declare proxy

Just go to `Maven-> conf-> setting.xml` file and add proxy

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>global.proxy.mycompany.com</host>
      <port>8000</port>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost,127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
 </proxies>
```

Comment: @user697911 this question is totally different and a new question but you can check edited answer.

Comment: @user697911 Particularly for Nexus you can check http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html

Comment: In order to define a proxy repository, I need to use a URL for the project I want to depend on. In this example above, which URL I need to use? That's the real question I am asking. It has URLs in <repository> tag in both <DistributionManagement> and <Repositories>. Thanks.

Comment: I already mentioned you cannot add more than one  `<repository>` child under  `<DistributionManagement>` FYI check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183636/maven-repository-proxy-confusion

Comment: In nexus to define a proxy repository, it needs a “remote storage location”, i.e. the location of remote repository being proxy. So in the above POM, which URL should I use?

Comment: Its all depend on you  which `url` you want to proxy.